# How update progress bar in fragment without using thread

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I try to update the progress of my progresseBar in a fragment but nothing happen. I don't use thread and I don't want to use one.

I found loads of subject on this and I try to use :
`setProgress(0)` and `setMax(max)` before update the value but that was unsucess.

The code :

```
  scoreABar.setProgress(0);
        scoreBBar.setProgress(0);
        scoreCBar.setProgress(0);
        scoreDBar.setProgress(0);
        scoreEBar.setProgress(0);
        scoreABar.setMax(100);
        scoreBBar.setMax(100);
        scoreCBar.setMax(100);
        scoreDBar.setMax(100);
        scoreEBar.setMax(100);
        scoreABar.setProgress((int) scoreA);
        scoreBBar.setProgress((int) scoreB);
        scoreCBar.setProgress((int) scoreC);
        scoreDBar.setProgress((int) scoreD);
        scoreEBar.setProgress((int) scoreE);
```

this code is in a method call in `OnCreatView()` of my fragment.
I'm sure that my values change but the progressBar no update.

Comment: Without threading you are displaying progress.That will not visible for you.

Answer (score 0):

Better to define each your progressbar in xml like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0" />
```

Then you set the progress with `scoreBar.setProgress((int) score);` Try it if it works for you

EDIT: Your task that you want to display progress for should be run in background thread, but you should always update the progress from main thread, e.g by using `activity.runOnUiThread()` method

Comment: I already define my progressbar like this. And this not working. I don't have task i just increment a variable in an other activity when the user make a specific action.

Comment: Please check the values of your `score` vars they should be in 0-100 range

Comment: Yes I have check this too and it's okay

Comment: One last idea, maybe you should try to set the progress like this:

`new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setProgress(score);
            }
        }); `